# Cannot release path created by CGPathCreateMutable in Swift

Tags: calayer, swift, cgpath

I have this simple code in Swift:

```
override var bounds : CGRect {
  didSet {
    if (bounds != oldValue) {
      var path = CGPathCreateMutable()
      CGPathAddEllipseInRect(path, nil, bounds)
      self.path = path
      CGPathRelease(path)
    }
  }
}
```

It's supposed to draw a circle that fills the layer when the layer's `bounds` changes.

This is ported from my old Objective-C code, which works fine:

```
- (void)setBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
  if (CGRectEqualToRect(self.bounds, bounds)) return;

  super.bounds = bounds;
  CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
  CGPathAddEllipseInRect(path, nil, bounds);
  self.path = path;
  CGPathRelease(path);
}
```

However, the Swift code crashes with some segfault. If I don't release the path, it's fine. If I don't set `self.path = path`, it's also fine (although nothing will show up, apparently). If both are present, it will crash.

I do think that a path created by `CGPathCreateMutable()` needs to be released though.. and that seems to be the case for ObjC. Does anyone know why it doesn't work in Swift? Or did I do anything wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: In swift3 `CGPathCreateMutable ()` become `CGMutablePath()`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to release CF objects in Swift. In your case, the `CGPathCreateMutable()` returns a `CGPath` object (not `CGPathRef`) and is memory-managed just the same as any swift object. They explained this in the WWDC video *[Swift Interoperability In Depth](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/407/)*

Comment: I see. Seems that the doc isn't updated then. Do you know if I can declare it as constant (`let path`)? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure if swift treats `CGPath` and `CGMutablePath` the same as `let x:String` and its mutable `var x:String` counterpart. Go ahead and try and tell us what you find out :)

Comment: The reason I ask is because `let path = CGPathCreateMutable()` works fine, which looks a bit strange. But yeah, I guess your explanation makes it much more reasonable now. Thanks!