# CGMutablePath type and releasing in Swift

Tags: swift, core-graphics

When reading the documentation, it is specified that `CGPathCreateMutable()` returns a mutable path and that you are responsible for releasing this object, but after some research I found [on this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176481/cannot-release-path-created-by-cgpathcreatemutable-in-swift) that :

> You don't need to release CF objects in Swift. In your case, the
>   `CGPathCreateMutable()` returns a `CGPath` object (not `CGPathRef`) and is
>   memory-managed just the same as any swift object.

But how is that possible since, when I cmd+click on CGPathCreateMutable() I see that :

```
public func CGPathCreateMutable() -> CGMutablePath
```

And

```
public typealias CGMutablePathRef = CGMutablePath
```

So, doesn't CGPathCreateMutable() returns a CGMutablePathRef in then end ? That should therefore be released ?

Also, I a struct/class, what type should I give to a property that will be initiated with `CGPathCreateMutable()` ?
Should it be `CGPath`, `CGMutablePath` or `CGMutablePathRef` ?

Thank you.

Comment: Released automatically with Swift: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900595/swift-cgpathrelease-and-arc, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176481/cannot-release-path-created-by-cgpathcreatemutable-in-swift. – `CGMutablePath` and `CGMutablePathRef` are aliases, choose whatever you prefer. I would use CGMutablePath because that is the documented return type

Comment: @MartinR Thank you so much ! I had misunderstood the typalias statement, thought that CGMutablePath was an alias of CGMutablePathRef, not the contrary.